# Linux / Ubuntu cannot find JVM

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, ide, java-7

I'm trying to install Netbeans to learn PHP.

I chose the all option from here

https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html>

And when I tried installing it on terminal, it said I needed JDK 7. After downloading and installing JDK 7 from

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

I tried to install netbeans again and it gave me the same message; that JDK is not installed  and I need to install it.

What should I do to get netbeans to isntall?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the Package manager? You should already have a JRE installed by default, but you should be able to use:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

To verify that you actually installed Java on your system you can try:

```
java -version
```

Once you have that you should be able to run netbeans by using the netbeans.sh script in the bin/ of the netbeans download. If I remember correctly it doesn't really install anything, just runs from there.